# Notify user about not allowed results via ASPECT pfcg_auth?

Tags: authorization, abap, opensql, cds

In "classic" ABAP authority checks, you would sometimes loop over a result list. If for at least one item the check fails, you'd notify the user about this and show only the items he's entitled to.
My question is: How would you do this in CDS using the pfcg_auth aspect?
For example:

```
define role my_role {
  grant select 
    on vbak
  where ( vkorg ) = aspect pfcg_auth ( v_vbak_vko, vkorg, actvt = '03' );
}
```

How would you tell that the selection found say 50 sales orders but the user is only authorized to display 40 of them?

Comment: In the rare cases where you really need this information, I guess you may create an API which runs under a Service User who is authorized to all data, a `SELECT COUNT(*)` would return the information you want.

Answer (score 3):

For `CDS` view select, there is a syntax that you can select bypassing the DCL [WITH PRIVILEGED ACCESS](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_data_source.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@)

You can select count(*) for the data in the database WITH PRIVILEGED ACCESS. if the numbers do not equal, you can raise the message.

Comment: this syntax was released in 752?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks great. The only downside here - if I got it right - is that I have to hit the view twice with the selection, am I correct?

Comment: Regarding the syntax, check the linked document. @Suncatcher

Comment: @Matthias yes. you need to hit the view twice. that's the only way. I mean this is what you needed which comes with consequences for performance if you have a large view.